# how to validate the filename and fileextension in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I tried to upload the json file with the name file name contains report .

if the file name have report , staticreport ,dynamic_report it should validate.otherfiles name should throws error message . File should be .json

```
report.json  ===> pass
staticreport.json===> pass
dynamic_report.json===> pass

report.doc  ===> fail
staticreport.xsl===> fail
dynamic_re5port.json===> fail
```

how do acheive using javascript

html code

```
 <input accept=".json" id="contained-button-file" multiple type="file"  onChange={ (e) => handleFile(e.target.files) } />
```

Javascipt code

```
const handleFile = (selectorFiles: FileList) => {   
var file1 = selectorFiles[0].name.split('.').pop(); 
if( file1 ==='json') {
//([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-\(\):])+(.json)$   
}
}
```

Comment: To be clear, your question is "How can I validate filename and file extension within Javascript?", right? And your list of valid filenames are `report.json`, `staticreport.json`, and `dynamic_report.json`, correct? If that is the case, you should be able to quickly verify the full filename (including extension) by doing an equality check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File type Validating .
Afte json file validate. checked filename consist of 'report'

```
 var allowedExtensions = /(\.json)$/i;

if (allowedExtensions.exec(selectorFiles[0].name) ) 
{
    if (selectorFiles[0].name.includes('report') ) {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use a regular expression to test if the name ends with `.json`.

```
var test = new RegExp('\\.json$');
var file = 'hello.json';
if (file.match(test)) {
    console.log('Yay!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below way

HTML code

```
<!-- File input field -->
<input type="file" id="file" onchange="return fileValidation()"/>
```

Javascript

```
function fileValidation(){
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('file');
    var filePath = fileInput.value;
    var allowedExtensions = /(\.json)$/i;
    if(!allowedExtensions.exec(filePath)){
        alert('Please upload file having extensions .json only.');
        fileInput.value = '';
        return false;
    }else{
       // perform your actions
        }
    }
}
```

for more [view here](https://www.codexworld.com/file-type-extension-validation-javascript/#:%7E:text=JavaScript%20Code,call%20for%20file%20extension%20validation.&text=Image%20file%20extensions%20regex%20is,the%20regex%20with%20allowed%20extensions.)

Comment: how to validate file name consist particular word